# Scale and position according size screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to Scale and position according size screen.as picture
When scaling the screen, the objects will have a position and scale change with it.many thank.sorry english my bad .[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your canvas, there is a component called canvas scaler and it has a property called UI Scale Mode, change it to scale with screen size. After that, you have to set the pivot points and anchors of your UI elements.

My suggestion would be checking [this article](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html), it describes everything step by step exactly for your example. I'm sure you'll have a really good understanding after finishing this article.

Comment: but it's not UI, it's gameobject, image, sprite

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Attach this script to the circle element in your canvas and tweak the variables.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UiElementScaleManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    private RectTransform rectTransform = null;
    [SerializeField] [Range(-200, 200)] private float offsetX = 85f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(-200, 200)] private float offsetY = 5f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 200)] private float width = 10f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 200)] private float height = 10f;
    [Tooltip("If checked then height variable will not be used.")]
    [SerializeField] private bool preserveAspect = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectTransform.pivot = Vector2.zero;
        rectTransform.anchorMax = Vector2.zero;
        rectTransform.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Screen.width * width / 100, ((preserveAspect) ? Screen.width * width : Screen.height * height) / 100);
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(Screen.width * offsetX / 100, Screen.height * offsetY / 100);
    }

}
```